In the dm_tran_locks DMV in SQL Server, why is the request mode set to "S" on an update statement
This relates to SQL Server 2019. If I run the sql:
SELECT
  GETDATE() as now,
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, transaction_begin_time, GETDATE()) as tran_elapsed_time_seconds,
  st.session_id,
  txt.text, 
  *
FROM
  sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st ON st.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON st.session_id = sess.session_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections conn ON conn.session_id = sess.session_id
    OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(conn.most_recent_sql_handle)  AS txt
where sess.session_id in ('69','116')
ORDER BY
  tran_elapsed_time_seconds DESC;


  SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,
    request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,
    resource_description
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
    WHERE resource_database_id =7
    and request_session_id in ('69','116')


How is this possible? I am expecting to see a "U" request mode.
The backstory to this, is there are lots of identical update statements on the same database with open transactions but with no sign of blocked sessions due to locking.
This is not causing an issue that I'm aware of, but I'm just trying to understand this from a learning perspective.

Those S locks are on the database.  They prevent other users from dropping the database or changing its state.

argh! yes thanks - the update didn't actually do anything (the where clause didn't bring back any rows), but sql still shows that as an open transaction. Thank you both!
